# Azure Active Directory B2C SignOut Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I'm integrating Azure ActiveDirectory B2C in an MVC ASP.NET Core web app. I've added the following config:

- in appsettings.json

```
  "AzureADB2C": {
      "Instance": "https://tenant.b2clogin.com",
      "ClientId": "11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
      "Domain": "tenant.onmicrosoft.com",
      "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
      "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_SUSI",
      "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_SUSI"
  }
```

Note: I've replace my real tenant and client id with dummy values in the above configuration sample.

- and in Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

namespace WebApp
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            ConfigurationManager configuration = builder.Configuration;

            IServiceCollection services = builder.Services;

            services
                .AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(configuration.GetSection(Constants.AzureAdB2C));

            services.AddControllersWithViews();

            services.AddRazorPages().AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

            // this is for debugging purposes
            services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(
                OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                options =>
                {
                    options.Events.OnAccessDenied = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnAccessDenied");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnAuthenticationFailed = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnAuthenticationFailed");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnAuthorizationCodeReceived");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnMessageReceived = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnMessageReceived");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnRedirectToIdentityProvider");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnRemoteFailure = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnRemoteFailure");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnRemoteSignOut = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnRemoteSignOut");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnTicketReceived = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnTicketReceived");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnTokenResponseReceived = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnTokenResponseReceived");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnTokenValidated = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnTokenValidated");
                    };
                    options.Events.OnUserInformationReceived = async context => {
                        Console.WriteLine("OnUserInformationReceived");
                    };
                });

            var app = builder.Build();

            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

The sign up and sign in flows work perfect but when trying to sign out it fails.

I'm triggering the Signed out process through /MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignedOut

The problem is that the process cycles infinitely between OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut and OnSignedOutCallbackRedirect.

Any ideas on how to make it work properly?

Comment: Have you added the `Signout` URL in the `App Registration` =>`Redirect URI`.

Comment: If you have already added, make sure it is same in both `redirect uri` and `appsettings.json` file.

Comment: Could you please share the error which you got.

Comment: There is no error, just an infinite loop

Comment: in portal I've configured https://localhost:7189/signout-oidc for Signout URL

Comment: Will check from my end and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

In your Startup.cs file, modify the OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut event to set the post_logout_redirect_uri parameter explicitly. Replace the existing OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut event with the following code:

```
options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut = async context =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("OnRedirectToIdentityProviderForSignOut");

    // Set the post_logout_redirect_uri parameter
    context.ProtocolMessage.SetPostLogoutRedirectUri(context.Properties.RedirectUri);

    await Task.CompletedTask;
};
```